# Moment.js: The result is always "a few seconds ago" in firefox/ie

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, momentjs

I'm from UTC +8 timezone and when I trying to convert `2014-06-04 12:51:53 +0800` /from Rails/ timestamp to my timezone. But it's only work in chrome and all others browers can't applying the UTC timezone. And result is always `a few seconds ago`. Here is the how I using it:

```
window.updateTimestamps = (elements)->
  moment.lang('mn')
  moment().tz("Asia/Ulaanbaatar").format()
  elements.each( ->
    timestamp = moment(new Date($(@).data('datetime')))
    $(@).html(timestamp.fromNow())
  )


$(document).on('ready', ->

  moment.tz.add
    zones:
      "Asia/Ulaanbaatar": [
        "7:7:32 - LMT 1905_7 7:7:32"
        "7 - ULAT 1978 7"
        "8 Mongol ULA%sT"
      ]

    rules:
      Mongol: [
        "1983 1984 3 1 7 0 0 1 S"
        "1983 1983 9 1 7 0 0 0"
        "1985 1998 2 0 8 0 0 1 S"
        "1984 1998 8 0 8 0 0 0"
        "2001 2001 3 6 8 2 0 1 S"
        "2001 2006 8 6 8 2 0 0"
        "2002 2006 2 6 8 2 0 1 S"
      ]
    links: {}
```

Here is the HTML I'm trying to convert:

```
<abbr class="time-ago" data-datetime="2014-06-04 12:51:53 +0800"></abbr>
```

Here is the code:

```
  timeAgos = $('abbr.time-ago')
  window.updateTimestamps(timeAgos)
  setInterval(window.updateTimestamps, 60000, timeAgos)
```

Thank you for answer. I have no idea? Plz help me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Javascript console shows a warning when trying to initialize moment.js with your date, and recommends to [read this bug report](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407). You'll have to convert your date to ISO format

```
>>> moment("2014-06-04 12:51:53 +0800").fromNow()
"a few seconds ago"
>>> moment("2014-06-04T12:51:53+0800").fromNow()
"7 days ago"
```

or use a format specifier instead:

```
>>> moment("2014-06-04 12:51:53 +0800", "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss +ZZ").fromNow()
"7 days ago"
```